# JS Promise Undefined Behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, angular-promise, es6-promise

**The Problem**: need to cancel a promise

Is it possible to *cancel* or *ignore* a promise mid execution and replace it with another one at runtime so that only its current state resolves?

In production, I am using angular `$timeout` which defines a `cancel()` method. I mimicked it to be run in node:

```
//Mimic AngularJS's $timeout
function MyTimeout(delay) {
    var t = null;
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        t = setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
    p.realtimeout = t;
    return p;
}
MyTimeout.cancel = function (myto) {
    clearTimeout(myto.realtimeout);
    /*
     * there is no way to appropriately cancel an existing Promise
     * the best I can do in try and change the state of myto to a rejected
     * Promise. Which doesn't help here since it doesn't truly cancel the last
     * Promise...
     */
    myto = Promise.reject("some reason");
};


var x = null;

function changeState() {
    var delay;

    if (x === null) {
        delay = 1000;
    } else {
        MyTimeout.cancel(x);
        delay = 3000;
    }

    x = MyTimeout(delay).then(print_delay);

    function print_delay() {
        console.log("EXECUTED: %s", delay);
    }
}


changeState();

x.then(function () {
    console.log("DONE");
}).catch(console.error);

changeState();
```

**NodeJS Output**

```
(node:12461) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): some reason
(node:12461) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

EXECUTED: 1000
DONE
EXECUTED: 3000
```

**Expected Outcome**: `EXECUTED: 3000` should print once. Since the flag is set and `x` has been set accordingly. `x` should point to that execution context.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context on what you hope to accomplish? That might help us understand the best way to solve for this.

Comment: A promise is resolved once. Maybe i'm wrong but you could use two Promises and use `Promise.race` for listening to the first resolved Promise. You'll Also need some logic un order to reject the first promise.

Comment: *"`.then()` gets called twice."* It shouldn't. `.then` is only attached to one promise. Creating and assigning a new promise to  `mypromise` doesn't magically move all callbacks from the previous promise. After you called `strangeFunc()`, you have an unhandled promise.

Comment: No, you cannot swap out `mypromise` after it's already being used, but you can change how it will be resolved.

Comment: @Bergi why not? Its just a variable.

Comment: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.", why have I been downvoted?

Comment: The variable doesn't matter, I'm talking about the object. Changing the variable reference does not affect the first promise and its handlers at all. You need to affect the resolution process of the promise that you already have.

Comment: and how do I do that? that's exactly what I need to do, I need to change how and when the original promise gets resolved...

Comment: you are arguing that I need to change how the original promise gets resolved, but there is no way to change that after the promise has been created...that is the issue.

Comment: Yes, you need to create it in a way so that you can change afterwards when/how `resolve` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot swap out `mypromise` or `x` after it's already being used, as changing the variable reference does not affect the first promise and its handlers at all. You need to affect the resolution process of the promise that you already have, and for that you need to create it in a way so that you can change afterwards when/how `resolve` is called:

```
function variableDelay(x) {
    var timer = 0;
    var end;
    return {
        promise: new Promise(resolve => {
            end = () => {
                timer = -1;
                resolve(x);
            };
        }),
        setDelay(d) {
            if (timer < 0) throw new Error("too late");
            if (timer > 0) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(end, d);
            return this;
        }
    };
}


const {promise:x, setDelay:changeState} = variableDelay();
changeState(1000);
x.then(() => {
    console.log("DONE");
}).catch(console.error);
changeState(3000);
```

Comment: the first Promise still executes the resolve function, is there a way to defer this execution only after the context was changed? also missing a `)` for the `new Promise`

Comment: No, the promise doesn't execute anything, it's `setDelay` that schedules `end` (with `resolve`).

Comment: a basic scheduler that will resolve the promise when we are ready...got it